# Is there a way to detect when an object's properties have been changed?

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I detect if an object's properties have changed in Javascript? I'm specifically looking to call a function when the amount of properties on an object has changed (whether it has gained or lost properties). I'd like to avoid using methods and to set and change the object's properties as that would get rather clumsy rather quickly, and `setInterval` is obviously not an option. So, is this possible?

---

Edit: I'm specifically looking for a way to get the length of an object's properties via a `length` property similar to what's on the Array object. I assumed they changed the length whenever an index was added or removed, but apparently this isn't the case. How did the original designers of Javascript manage this?

Comment: It will be possible in ES6, I think...

Comment: You could do a 100ms interval. That wouldn't hurt performance...

Comment: So it's definitely not possible now? That's too bad... any ideas when ES6 will roll around? Also, I'm likely to have quite a few of these objects so like I said, `setInterval` is not an option.

Comment: ES6 is coming in December, but it's the browsers which have to implement the new stuff, so it could take 5 years to have this feature cross-browser. Read here (it's in Firefox already): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Btw, you can get the length with `Object.keys( obj ).length`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Oh, thanks for the link about the proxies, I won't be using them until they're fully supported though... very interesting, nonethelesss. Also, I'd like to wrap getting the length in a property, such that I can call `myObj.length` like the Array object's length property. So maybe wrapping `Object.keys(obj).length` in some of property/function might help? I dunno how to make a function execute without the `()`'s though.

Comment: That would only be possible with a getter, but it would break in IE8 (IE implemented getters in IE9). If you need it to work in IE, the best thing you can do is: `myObj.length();`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Ah, okay, that's the answer I was looking for. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to sum up everything I said via comments: ES6 will provide proxies which should enable handlers for events like "new property", or "property deleted". (I haven't looked into it that much, though.) Unfortunately, it will take years until proxies become cross-browser.

As for, the `length` property for objects, you could define a getter function for that, but that would break in IE8, since IE only implemented getters in IE9. So, that leaves you with a `length()` method. So:

```
function objectLength () {
    return Object.keys( this ).length;
}
```

and then, you make sure that your object has this function (either as an own property, or an inherited property):

```
yourObj.length = objectLength;
```

or

```
YourConstructor.prototype.length = objectLength;
```

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I forgot to mention, `Object.keys` is not cross-browser (it's not implemented in IE8/7, FF 3.6/5), but you can manually implement it for those browsers. Either include the code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), or just include [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) to your page.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the common way to do it is to have a getter and setter type of functions to do it, similar to how backbone does it's models. You modify the data via the function, then the function does additional processing (like execute listeners, check properties etc.) before executing what you want to do.

```
function ListenableObject(data){

    var that = this;
    this.data = data;
    this.listeners = [];

    this.edit = function(newvalues){
        //modify data
        //execute listeners
    }

    this.addListener = function(callback){
        that.listeners.push(callback);
    }
}

var mydata = new ListenableObject({'foo':'bar'});

mydata.addListener(function(){...callback...});

mydata.edit(somedata);
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, I'd like to avoid using getters and setters on my object if possible. Are there any other ways to detect if I assign a new property to an object like `myObj["hello"] = world`?

Comment: Would `myObj["hello"](world)` be satisfactory? `myObj["hello"] = function(someVar) {myObj._hello = someVar; someOtherProcessing();}`

Comment: @soniiic: No, because then I'd have to create a function for every property I wanted assign, right?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville yup. if it is all for one property, then i agree that it is rather bulky.

Comment: Oh, no, this would be for lots of properties, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, based on your requirements, is that it is not possible to do what you're trying to do.  At least, not yet.  There are a few techniques you can use to get the same functionality with a minimal impact on your code.  Here's one of my personal favorites -- discovered somewhere on SO -- I'll link if I can find.

```
function myObj(){

   var _this = this;

   // onUpdate callbacks
   this.onBeforeUpdate = [];
   this.onAfterUpdate  = [];

   this.UpdateProperty = function( prop, value ){

      // execute onBeforeUpdate callbacks...  
      for ( var i = 0; i < _this.onBeforeUpdate.length; i++ )
         _this.onBeforeUpdate[i]();

      _this[prop] = value;

      // execute onAfterUpdate callbacks...
      for ( var i = 0; i < _this.onAfterUpdate.length; i++ )
         _this.onAfterUpdate[i]();
   };

}
```

Of course, this example can be made to perform even better with some liberal use of prototype assignments, but you can see the intent.